# Laravel Eloquent ORM get function working Confusion

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am new to laravel so can anybody explain me that what exactly get() function of eloquent ORM does. I have following query and I need to know on which line the database is queried.

```
$propertiesQuery = Property::with('country', 'city','bannerInvoicesCount','rejectedBannerInvoicesCount')
           ->where('is_deleted','=',1);  
        if(Auth::user()->type == 'po') {
            $propertiesQuery->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        }

        $propertiesQuery->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
        $properties = $propertiesQuery->get();
```

Now in above code I have accessed Model once whether that is the point when db is queried or when I have called get() function. I am not been able to comprehend the internal working of this. That exactly on which statement the query is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Raza before eloquant $propertiesQuery->get() step, it prepare your query like:

```
select * from table where user_id=1
```

and when you call/trigger the $propertiesQuery->get() method, it forward your query to database and fetch the records against your query. like, normally we do in plain sql:

```
eg: mysql_query($query);
then mysql_fetch_assoc() etc methods
```

so get() method contains on: execute the query and return all the records in the array format.

I hope it will help you.